# How to convert byte[512] to string 1024 length

Tags: c#, .net, byte

This bit of code produces an array of size 512, it converts a string that was originally 1024 characters in length and has hex data.

```
byte[] content = Enumerable.Range(0, data.Length)
.Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
.Select(x => Convert.ToByte(data.Substring(x, 2), 16))
.ToArray();
```

I like to know how to reverse this so taking a byte[512] I want to produce the 1024 length string containing the hex data.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
var result = string.Join("", 
                inputString.Select(c => String.Format("{0:X2}", Convert.ToInt32(c))));
```